# How to callback a Scrapy spider method upon receiving SIGINT or Scrapyd's cancel.json call?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

In Scrapy, when we press CTRL+C we see `Received SIGINT, shutting down gracefully. Send again to force` in logs that comes from [this code](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/crawler.html).

Or when we request cancel.json of Scrapyd [following code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/f916d9b78b9bb7c8465277a49c24f876eaf3ed7e/scrapyd/webservice.py#L59) is executed

I want to catch those signals in my Spider, so any of those is called, one of my Spider's callback method should also be called.

I have searched a lot about this but did not find any help.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `signal` to catch those CTRL+C or TERM signal sent my scrapyd

```
import signal

def custom_terminate_spider(self, sig, frame):

    self.logger.info(self.crawler.stats.get_stats()) #print stats if you want
    
    #dangerous line, it will just kill your scrapy spider running immediately
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)

def start_requests(self):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.custom_terminate_spider) #CTRL+C
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.custom_terminate_spider) #sent by scrapyd
```